# How do I implement isLocationOnEdge of Google Maps API in Go?

Tags: google-maps, go, geo, polyline

I am using google maps API through [this library](https://godoc.org/googlemaps.github.io/maps). I have a route that I got using the direction API. Now I need to know whether given point is on the polyline. Google JS geometry library has function [isLocationOnEdge](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge). But I can't find something similar in Golang.

Comment: Have a look at implementation of the `isLocationOnEdge` for Android SDK written in Java and try to port it to Go: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java

Comment: find the equation of the line between any two points in the polyline and then see of the point in question is solved by that equation